# div floating on top of other divs with css only

Tags: css, html

I looked around for a solution and it seems that there are some around, but I don't seem to make it work, any idea will be greatly appreciated.

I've got three divs into a div container (centered) used as a background (`z-index : -10;`). I would like to float another div (it will be another container `z-index : 5;`) on top of the previous ones.

HTML below:

```
<div class="div-backall ">
<div class="div-backtop">
        <p>1111</p>
    </div>
<div class="div-backmid">
        <p>2222</p>
    </div>
<div class="div-backbottom ">
        <p>3333</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div-main">
    <p>Main text goes here</p>
</div>
```

CSS below:

```
.div-backall {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index : 1;
    margin-left : auto;
    margin-right : auto;
    position : absolute;
}
.div-backtop {
    width: 90%;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: #D8E4F8;
    margin: -5px 0 0 0;
    position : absolute;
    margin-left : 5%;
    margin-right : 5%;          
}
.div-backmid {
    width: 90%;
    height: 75%;
    background-color: #F1EFE2;
    margin: 14% 0 0 0;
    position : absolute;
    margin-left : 5%;
    margin-right : 5%;      
}
.div-backbottom {
    width: 90%;
    height: 5%;
    background-color: #D8E4F8;
    margin: 70% 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    position : absolute;
    margin-left : 5%;
    margin-right : 5%;  
}

.div-main{
    width: 70%;
    height: 85%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left : 10%;
    margin-right : 10%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index : 2;
    border : thin solid Black;
    position : absolute;
    margin-top : 5%; 
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I can obtain the floating effect using `margin-top : -800px;` but it's a rubish solution. Also I cannot get the later centered. Is it possible this with CSS only? Shall I look to a js solution?

Thanks,
Lee

Comment: show your example in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

**z-index** is only work with position `relative, absolute & fixed`. Write like this:

```
    .div-backtop,
    .div-backbottom,
    .div-main{
     position:relative;
    }
   .div-backtop{
     z-index:1;
    }
   .div-main{
     z-index:2;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure if I explained correctly what I intended. From your answer .div-main is just pushed last is the page. I would like to see it on top of the .div-backall container - and centered.

Answer (score 1):

To use z-index you have to use position absolute for every div because the relative position doesn't support z-index

Comment: That is close, thank you, but how can I center the two containers having absolute position?

Comment: To center you can use this in your css:
left: 50%;
margin-left: -<half of image width>px;

Answer (score 0):

please make sure how the output could be?
i am not able to do how to give answer for your problem...as i understand i given one solution..hope you will get from this

```
margin-top : -700px;
    position:relative;
```

please make changes in this

```
.div-main{
    width: 70%;
    height: 85%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left : 10%;
    z-index : 5;
    border : thin solid Black;
    position : relativ;
    margin-top : -700px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```